# Maven profile configuration with common plugins in different profiles

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I have a maven project which uses various plugins. One of those is the [frontend maven plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin), which we use to run npm commands and build the output inside the war file.

When I am developing the backend part of the application I don't want that plugin to start, while in other situations (like when I'm developing web component which need to be built) I want to run this plugin.

As far as I know, [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) could be used to address this issue.
I want that the profiles are configured at project level because have to be used by many developers.

In this case, I would create:

- a profile where I skip test (excluding frontend maven plugin)
- a profile including tests (excluding frontend maven plugin)
- a profile that includes frontend maven plugin for test locally some execution of the frontend maven plugin, while not others
- 2 profiles (test and prod for test and production environment) that includes some extra frontend maven plugin's executions in the build process

I would like to know if I can configure it with profiles or if I have to manage it with command line arguments, excluding the steps that I don't want to run in a specific moment, but would not so much comfortable.

This is an idea of how I would configure those profiles:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <!-- skip tests -->
     </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <!-- frontend-maven-plugin -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- other conf -->
     </profile>
     <profile>
         <id>prod</id>
           <plugins>
            <plugin>
                 <!-- frontend-maven-plugin -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- other conf -->
     </profile>
</profiles>
```

### Questions

1. Is this pattern a good starting point or do I have to use profiles in a different way?
2. How can I use the same plugin with same configuration (test and prod) without repeating the same code in both the profile sections?
3. Do I have to use profiles for different reasons? Is there a better configuration to address this situation?